# Making value invalid on scroll doesn't make property revert to initial value

Tags: css, scroll, css-animations, css-variables

I am looking to make a CSS `animation` start running once the parent of the element I want to animate is fully scrolled into view with pure CSS using the [View Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/scroll-driven-animations/#getting-practical-with-view-progress-timeline) (currently only working in Chrome 115+).

---

A bit of background on what I am attempting to do here, illustrated with a simple `:hover` example. Let's say I want to make an element spin infinitely, but only while it's hovered, the `animation` is `paused` otherwise.

I can do something like this:

```css
div {
  margin: 2em auto 0;
  width: 8em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: color-mix(in hsl, hotpink calc(var(--bit, 0)*100%), gold);
  animation: rot 2s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: var(--bit, paused)
}

@keyframes rot { to { rotate: 1turn } }

div:hover { --bit: 1 }
```

```html
<div>Hover me!</div>
```

The `animation-play-state` is set to the custom property `--bit`, which hasn't been explicitly set anywhere (this is important), but has a fallback value of `paused`. So the `animation` is `paused` while the element isn't hovered.

If the element is hovered, then `--bit` is explicitly set to `1`, which is an invalid value for `animation-play-state`. So then `animation-play-state` reverts to [its initial value, which is `running`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state).

I prefer this technique because it allows me to change the values of multiple properties on `:hover` by only setting `--bit` to `1` (in the example above, I'm also changing the `background` using `--bit` and other properties can be changed as well, but I wanted to leave this example as simple as possible).

---

Back to triggering animations on scroll. Let's say we have a `header` and a `section`, both `100vh` tall. The `section` contains the element we want to animate. When this `section` containing our element has fully (`100%`) entered the viewport, we change the value of `--bit` to `1`, which is an invalid value for `animation-play-state`, so it should make it revert to initial value, `running`, which should make the rotation start. Except that doesn't happen.

```css
* { margin: 0 }

header, section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center; 
  height: 100vh
}

section {
  animation: b linear both;
  animation-timeline: view();
  animation-range: entry 100% entry 100%
}

@keyframes b { to { --bit: 1 } }

div {
  width: 9em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: 
    color-mix(in hsl, hotpink calc(var(--bit, 0)*100%), gold);
  animation: rot 2s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: var(--bit, paused)
}

@keyframes rot { to { rotate: 1turn } }
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Scroll!</h2>
</header>
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

You can see that when the section has fully entered into view, the value of `--bit` has been explicitly set to `1` and it also has been used to alter the `background` from `gold` to `hotpink`.

[image: dev tools screenshot showing the computed value of --bit is 1 and our div element is hotpink]

However, the element hasn't started rotating. And if we check the computed value for `animation-play-state`, it's still `paused`, even though the computed value for `--bit` is now `1`.

[image: dev tools screenshot showing the animation-play-state value is still paused]

**What is happening here? How can I make this work? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?**

---

Triggering transitions this way works just fine.

```css
* { margin: 0 }

header, section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center; 
  height: 100vh
}

section {
  animation: b linear both;
  animation-timeline: view();
  animation-range: entry 100% entry 100%
}

@keyframes b { to { --bit: 1 } }

div {
  width: 9em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  rotate: calc(var(--bit, 0)*1turn);
  background: color-mix(in hsl, hotpink calc(var(--bit, 0)*100%), gold);
  transition: 2s;
  transition-property: rotate, background-color
}
```

```html
<header><h2>Scroll!</h2></header>
<section><div></div></section>
```

---

Using a style query to change the value for `animation-play-state` works fine as well. You can see that as soon as you scroll back up a bit from being scrolled all the way, the animation pauses and the `background` changes from `hotpink` back to `gold.`

```css
* { margin: 0 }

header, section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center; 
  height: 100vh
}

section {
  --bit: 0;
  animation: b linear both;
  animation-timeline: view();
  animation-range: entry 100% entry 100%
}

@keyframes b { to { --bit: 1 } }

div {
  width: 9em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: color-mix(in hsl, hotpink calc(var(--bit)*100%), gold);
  animation: rot 2s linear infinite;
}

@container style(--bit: 0) {
  div { animation-play-state: paused }
}

@keyframes rot { to { rotate: 1turn } }
```

```html
<header><h2>Scroll!</h2></header>
<section><div></div></section>
```

But I find this clunky and I'd really rather find a way to get the invalid value technique to work. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure but your issue is probably related to this:

> However, any custom property used in a @keyframes rule becomes animation-tainted, which affects how it is treated when referred to via the var() function in an animation property. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/)</sup>

The `--bit` is used in a keyframes and is defined within an animation property so is concerned about that part but I never understood what "animation-tainted" means.

Maybe if you define the custom property using `@property` it will work (I cannot try it)

Comment: I avoided using `@property` as it introduces another problem: it gives `--b` a fixed type. This means that `--b` is always a number, so `var(--b, paused)` never uses the fallback value of `paused` but instead the numeric `initial-value` set in the `@property` block. Since a numeric value is always invalid for `animation-play-state`, this always reverts to its initial value of `running`, meaning that always runs, not only when the parent is scrolled enough. It's never paused. Test: https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/WNYqdrd uncomment the `@property` block by adding a slash at the end of line 1.

Comment: As for the "animation-tainted" part, that has always been really weird for me too, so I'm not sure if that's it or not. On the one hand, I know it ***is*** why I cannot set a property inside a keyframe to a variable that gets animated (for example https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/oebQjY/17c3a1101211ce7c17accd45b430debf) and as far as I recall, making the `animation-duration` depend on an animated custom property doesn't work for the same reason either. But then if I use a style query https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/qBQzPGY it's still `animation-play-state` depending on `--b` and it works.